# How to properly execute a parachain backup and recover the chain state

Tags: parachain, recovery

I'm trying to execute a recovery from a manually stalled parachain.

I'm doing the following,

1. Backup the base-path folder for the block #30
2. Let the parachain produce more blocks, until #40
3. Brick the parachain so it stops producing blocks
4. From the backup, generate a chain spec using `export-state`
5. With the new chain spec, generate a genesis-head using `export-genesis-state`
6. Delete the bricked base-path folder, and replace with the backup
7. Restart the node with the generated chain spec and the backup base-path
8. Using the new exported genesis state, execute a `force_set_current_head` from the Relay Chain.

I'm assuming there's something not correct in my procedure, as the parachain logs the following error

```
2024-03-28 13:04:00 [Parachain] Could not find the header of the genesis block in the database! block_hash=0x6d202ad77996c9ef49b6074f0d130cd6cdbc0547a69f66b0243b069471eaa79c
```

So there is any other method or procedure to properly set a previous state to a parachain?